# Proving Uniform Convergence

Tags: uniform-convergence

ST the sequence $f_n$ where $f_n(x)=e^{-nx}$ is point wise but not uniformely convergent in $[0,\infty[$. Also show that the convergence is uniform in $[k,\infty[$, $k$ being a positive number.

I am able to show that point wise limit is $f(x)=0 \ \ \forall \ x$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given then,

$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|e^{-nx}-0|=e^{-nx}<\epsilon$

we can choose $m\in N$ such that $\large \large m>{1\over {\epsilon xlogx}} $

so as $x\rightarrow \infty \ \ \ m\rightarrow 0$ , but $m>0$ so not uniformely convergent. Is it good ?

How do i proceed further ?

Comment: $(f_n)$ does not converge pointwise to the zero function on $[0,\infty)$. It converges to the *discontinuous* function that takes the value $1$ at $x=0$ and the value $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent on $[0,+\infty)$ to the function $f$ defined by

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}\\1&\text{if}\ x=0\\
0&\text{if}\ x>0\end{array}\right.$$
and since $f$ isn't continous then the convergence isn't uniform on $[0,+\infty)$.

For all $k>0$ we have
$$\forall x\geq k,\quad|f_n(x)|\leq e^{-nk}\to_{n\to\infty}0$$
so the sequence is uniformly convergent on $[k,+\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks !!, I need to be more careful with the point-wise limits in that case :)

Comment: Yes that's right:)

Comment: 1 side question, If $f_n(x)=tan^{-1}nx, x\ge 0$ what will be its point wise limit in $[0,b]$ ??

Comment: The limit $f$ is defined by: $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\pi/2$ if $x>0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how $f(x)=\pi /2$ for $x>0$ ? I am missing out on some concept here i think

Comment: Take any $x>0$ then $nx\to\infty$ and the function $\arctan t\to\pi/2$ if $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Oh !! I forgot to take limit to infinity. Thanks again, convergence etc is one topic in maths that really scares me. Lol !!